# SAS ODS tagsets excelxp gridlines option

Tags: sas

While exporting the data from a SAS dataset to Excel using ods tagsets.excelxp, I do not want to see the gridlines.

I have tried option gridlines='off' / gridlines='no' but that did not work and I looked at the guide here https://support.sas.com/rnd/base/ods/odsmarkup/excelxp_help.html, which says use gridlines-'no' for turning off gridlines while printing.

How can I turn it off in the excel itself.

Comment: Show the actual code you used? Can you post an example using SASHELP.CLASS as the input data?  Also why are you using TAGSETS.EXCELXP instead of EXCEL?   Do you really need an xml file instead of an xlsx file? Are you running a really old version of SAS?

Comment: Usually this means you don't have the latest version of tagsets. what version do you have? it's in the log at the top of the code after you run it. Or go to Page Layout in Excel and turn Gridlines off.